# Add a callback to .scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you add a simple callback to the following code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("html,body").scrollTop(0);
});
```

I'm trying this but it's not working for some odd reason:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("html,body").scrollTop(0), function(){
       alert("done")
   };
});
```

Comment: Why would you need to do that? scrollTop in jQuery is synchronous and take effect immediately.

Comment: It forces the page to scroll to top when someone reloads the page. I need to do an animation and would it to trigger only after the page has scrolled up (hence the callback)